# Ignore function anomaly when used to reading files in c++

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to use the ignore function skip a few lines, but the parameters of the function are oddly different. Shouldn't it be a streamsize(amount of characters and a delimiter(to stop ignoring up to the assigned character). The problem i am having is that the 2nd parameter for me it is required to be an integer. While i want to use "\n" it doesn't accept it because it is char.

> std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::ignore(std::streamsize,int)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [2]' to 'int'

Comment: `"\n"` is an array of 2 `char`s (`'\n'` and `'\0'`).  `'\n'` is a `char`.

Comment: I have changed the double quotation marks into single and it seems to be working. I will research on what the difference is. You mind telling me why they are different while you are at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"\n"` (with double quotes) is a string literal, not a `char` literal.  In this case, it's an array of two `char`s; equivalent to `{'\n', '\0'}`.

`'\n'` (with single quotes) is a `char` literal.  It represents a single newline character.

`std::istream::ignore` accepts only a single character as its delimiter, so you have to use the latter.

---

Note: `std::istream::ignore`'s second parameter is an `int` rather than a `char` so that it can accommodate the extra "end of file" pseudo-character.  The eof value has to be different than any valid character value, so the type used for the delimiter must be wider than `char`.